# MailApp.sendEmail() in Google Apps Script not sending email

Tags: google-apps-script

We establish Google G Suite for our clients and over the last few weeks, we have found that Google Apps Script does not process the MailApp.sendEmail() as expected.  It only happens in new G Suite account and the exact same code in existing account function as expected.

```
function testemail(){
  MailApp.sendEmail("gordon@........", "TEST", "Hello world");
  return;
}
```

Email address that we have used are valid email.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like an account configuration error. Try to compare the configurations. You'll probably be better off asking this in the [webapps stackexchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/g-suite-administrator/). Also, check if you're able to sent emails from the gmail interface in this new account.

Answer (score 9):

Try using [GmailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String))

```
// The code below will send an email with the current date and time.
var now = new Date();
GmailApp.sendEmail("mike@example.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString());
```

which is the recommended one now.

Comment: Oddly the GmailApp.sendEmail() works.  Thanks for the heads up. Should have tried that first but good note for other with the same issue.  Still the MailApp.sendEmail with the same parameter does not work.  Maybe a Google Service issue in our area!  Thanks again.