# MailApp.sendEmail method doesn't get through to accounts with URL in the body - Message Blocked

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

I am working on Google Apps Script. I am trying to send email as follows:

```
function test_sendmail(){
  var subject = "subject";
  var body = "https://www.google.com/";
  var emailBody = body;
  var options = {
    htmlBody: body
  }

  var recipient = "XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com";

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, emailBody, options);
}
```

`"XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"`(email address A) is not valid, but it's only for showing you an example.  I use a real email address in the GAS execution.

The GAS execution is run by another G-suite domain google account(email address B) by which account the code is written.

The email address A has editing rights to the spreadsheet that has the above code in the GAS editor.

But, the email from the above function doesn't get through the email address A. I got this email in the email address B.

[image]

LEARN MORE:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596?visit_id=637267406328019079-2003975007&rd=1

Then, I replace the email address with the email address B. and I tried to send it, and it did get through successfully.

Secondly, I changed the URL part:

```
var body = "https://www.google.com/";
```

to:

```
var body = "";
```

Then, the email successfully get through to both email addresses A and B.

The results listed as below:

[image]

The failure of sending email with URL to email address like the email address A has occurred recently like from 1 week or 2 weeks ago. Until then, the 4 cases had been successfully done before. I have no idea why this started happening recently.

I checked if the sender email address B is in the contact list of the recipient email address A.

It is not in `my contacts`.
[image]

But when I searched it, it appeared, so it seems in `all contacts`.

[image]

---

**Added 1:** 
I tried sending email to the email address C which is another G-suite mail address in the same domain as the email address B, but email address C doesn't have rights to the spreadsheet and the editor.

It sent to the email C successfully even it has no right to the spreadsheet.

---

**Added 2:** 
I tried sending email to the email address D which is other email address that is neither G-suite domain or @google.com address. The result is the same as the email address A.

---

Comment: @AlanWells I added it. Thank you.

Comment: @Rubén I added the information about contacts in the post. Yes, the content only include an URL and subject only include a single word as you see in the code above. I simplified the original code of real code. The code above is for testing purpose.

Comment: If the email is being blocked by the account that is not the owner of the script, then it may be that you have no control over that.  The administrator of the account that is blocking the email could have changed a setting.  Unless you have access to both GSuite domains?  Do you know the administrator of the domain that is blocking the email?  Have you asked them if they block certain content in emails?

Comment: @AlanWells the receiving account is my personal google account. I didn't change any thing or policy on this my account.

Comment: Does this happen with any other addresses? Does the behaviour change between `@gmail.com` or `@userBdomain.com` addresses?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I added some to my post to respond you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail anti-spam algorithms are complex. To prevent that the messages sent by your script being blocked by them, follow the guidelines on [Prevent mail to Gmail users from being blocked or sent to spam](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

---

Possible Workaround

One of my clients had the same issue, I replaced `MailApp.sendEmail(message)` by `GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body,options)` apparently this worked (No bounce messages after 10 minutes)

Rafa Guillermo added in a comment:

> Just want to add that in this case if this is an ongoing issue you should get your admin to contact [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

If you hasn't access to G Suite Support I think that you could report this issue to Google by using Google Feedback (Open Gmail web UI > click the settings button (gear icon) > Send feedback)

Related

- [MailApp.sendEmail() in Google Apps Script not sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53079323/1595451) (it looks that this is first Q/A about this issue that also suggest replace MailApp by GmailApp)
- [Message blocked when sending email from Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53262939/1595451)

Comment: Thank you. So, It might be that there is suspicions URL in email body. I refered to [this](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596). But the email had gotten through before. This started happening recently. Google changed the policy recently?

Comment: Yes, that's right. However, why the email whose body has just only the simple URL like "google.com" to be blocked? It can't be any suspicious.

Comment: Despite the policy changes, there are some dynamic components like people marking email messages as spam and overall spammers activity that could make the algorithms change which messages are marked as spam.

Comment: Unfortunately, the way that Google determines what content is acceptable and what isn't is flawed.  (June 3, 2020 - Maybe it will be better at some future time?) I believe that the cause of the blocked email is very likely something that Google did, and probably not either of the email accounts.  And you may never know exactly why it got blocked.

Comment: Just want to add that in this case if this is an ongoing issue you should get your admin to contact [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thank you. By the way, one of my clients had the same issue, I replaced MailApp.sendEmail(message) by GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body,options) apparently this worked.

Comment: @Herbert I added a possible workaround (it worked for one of my clients)

Comment: @Rubén  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body,options) just worked for my testing code. Thank you!

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Thank you!