# MailApp.sendEmail not working in specific cases

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, outlook, gmail

I am trying to make an application that will send me an email automatically every time there is a change done to the sheet. I know there are notifications that are able to do this but three things.

1. I need at a specific time and
2. I need it to a specific email.
3. I want it done for a specific range of cells. It seems like Google took out those features.

I already know that the `onEdit()` function doesnt really like when you send emails out, but Im trying to work around that to maybe compile a list of changes and send that list alone at a certain time, and then clear the list.

But I havnt even gotten there yet, because the `MailApp.sendEmail` is not working the way I need it to, I tried pretty much everything.
I set up a test case for me to send to an automated email to my work Gmail as follows.

```
function emailTest(){
  MailApp.sendEmail("currentGmail@gmail.com", "This is the subject", "This is the message");
}
```

This works great, however I need to send the email to my company domain email, which is using outlook, so I went ahead and made the following changes.

```
function emailTest(){
      MailApp.sendEmail("name@companyEmail.com", "This is the subject", "This is the message");
    }
```

And then nothing happens, simply nothing. So I change it my personal gmail, to see if anything gives.

```
function emailTest(){
          MailApp.sendEmail("personalGmail@gmail.com", "This is the subject", "This is the message");
        }
```

And it works! no issues nothing, so then I change it to my personal non-gmail email.

```
  function emailTest(){
              MailApp.sendEmail("personalEmail@aim.com", "This is the subject", "This is the message");
            }
```

And it still works.

My head is trying to wrap around whats going on. I try to send a manual email from my work Gmail account to my outlook Gmail account and it works as well.
I then say ok, let me just send the automated emails to my work Gmail and forward those emails to my outlook email. And that doesnt work. 
I then tried to send an email from my personal Gmail to my work Gmail and see if that gets forwarded, and it does. So I think and Im thinking maybe for some reason I cant forward emails that I send myself (the automation emails come in as you as the sender), so I make ANOTHER gmail account and I send the automation emails to the new Gmail and get that forwarded to my work outlook account. This however failed to work as well.

So I get on the phone with our tech support team and see if there is anything blocking outlook from receiving these messages, it seems like there isn't, but they really didn't know where to look.

Can anyone help me figure out whats going on?
Does Gmail have some sort of block to not send to business emails?
Does outlook have some of block not to accept certain emails that are flagged as automated?

A few notes:

- I used these methods for GmailApp as well.
- Yes I checked my junk mail for all of this
- The emails that are not being received are coming into my sent folder on Gmail.
- I tried using something like this as well: `GmailApp.sendEmail("efreiner@milliardbrands.com", 'From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()});`
- I also tried sending an email to a different outlook account to an outside company, that worked. And when I tried a college of mine with outlook it didnt work

**Update**
I just received this email from Google. 
I didnt try to send an email for a good few hours.
It seems like the email that was kicked back was sent yesterday, as its a reply to that email.
[image: Email from google kicking back the email]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MailApp.sendEmail method doesn't get through to accounts with URL in the body - Message Blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62156903/mailapp-sendemail-method-doesnt-get-through-to-accounts-with-url-in-the-body)

Comment: Tl;Dr the above link: There is an ongoing issue. Quick workaround instead of using `MailApp.sendEmail` use `GmailApp.sendEmail`

Comment: I tried GmailApp for all the above messages, @Rubén, that doesnt really help me, he at least gets an error, I get nothing

Comment: Please edit the question to add that you tried with GmailApp too. Also mention if you are able to send messages to your business account from the Gmail web UI.

Comment: There is another thing you can try - to use the Gmail API [directly](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) and lookup the response from the API - if there will be no pointers as to why, I think that only Google / Microsoft support teams can help you

Comment: @Ruben, I added that I used GmailApp, I mentioned before that I used the Gmail Web Ui.

Comment: @OlegValter this wasnt mean to be a coding project. Im not a developer in the company, I just have some development background, figured I would use it if it was clean. But I really dont want to make a big project out of this whole thing. Thanks for the info though. also, how can I contact google support team?

Comment: @EdonFreiner - well, you seem to have stumbled on something not so simple :)  If you have a GSuite account with a support plan - click on a link in Ruben's answer - it will take you to the support page - you will then have an option to contact support from admin console. If not - there is always the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191609) but it is not guaranteed

Comment: Btw, to eliminate one of the vectors - is the email that fails to be delivered even being sent? GmailApp, Gmail API and MailApp all use your account as if you sent the emails manually, so you should see the email in "Sent" folder (sorry if you mentioned, but I didn't find this info in your question)

Comment: I'd suggest you to contact G Suite support [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213), as @OlegValter said before. If you think this behaviour is reproducible using other accounts, you could report this in Issue Tracker too.

Comment: @Iamblichus Thanks for the tip, I dont have Gsuite, I made a regular google account. So I dont really have that perk

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks for the tip, it is in my sent folder. I will add that to the post

Comment: Thank you for checking, that, as I think you guessed already, leaves either gmail -> outlook or incoming -> outlook vectors. Btw, auto email `mailed-by` field is set to "maestro.bounces.google.com" and manual - to "gmail.com". I bet that Microsoft included this infrastructure either intentionally or by accident in stop lists

Comment: Which is why I would suggest you try one thing more - `GmailApp` has an optional parameter object, please, set the `from` field to your account email (e.g. with `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` if running manually) - it should relay the sendout as if it came from your account. I just checked, and it does indeed change the `mailed-by` field

Comment: @OlegValter, thanks, I tried that, it sent to my work gmail (just to test), I tried my outlook email, didnt work.

Comment: I see, well, that's a pity. One other thing, though, have you tried to also set the `name` option? This way the email should seem like it is sent exactly from a real person. Other than that it seems like the only option left is to check up on either of the support teams. Since the email is marked as sent, I am, contrary to other thread, inclined to think this is less likely a problem Google can help you with, but rather Microsoft support

Comment: Thanks @OlegValter, Ill give that a try tomorrow. I did get a kickback email from google, I updated the post up top. Its similar to what you had on your other post, so Ill have to take a look at that again. Thanks for your help

Comment: I would upvote twice if I could - it is a joy to see so much dedication to the question! Please, let us know if there is any update on this - unless your tech team didn't miss anything related to email security settings, this might point to a bigger underlying issue

Comment: Thank you, Im trying everything I could. I tried changing the name. No go. I took a look at the other post. It seems like his issue was that it was being blocked, my issue is that it couldnt be delivered. Ill go another search and try to see why that is the case, Ill try to give it another go.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the name of my email. I named my business gmail
personalName.companyName@gmail.com and we have a rule in a spam
organizer that blocks all emails with the company name in them that
comes from the outside. So it was a quick fix to whitelist my email
and it was all good to go.

Comment: Glad you resolved it! Still good to know that the issue was indeed tied to the outlook side of things and not an issue we should escalate. You should probably edit the answer to highlight the solution with `>` prefix for others to easily spot it

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean with the > prefix? Just add that to the beginning of my answer? What does that do?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just meant that if you start a line with ">", it will be formatted as quote)

Comment: huh, just the whitelist would be enough - but your call) Thanks!