# Unable to send emails outside my domain, emails bounce

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Gsuite account for my non-profit domain. I have an app script that is used to send emails on form submit via Google sheets.  I am able to send emails if the domain is same as mydomain.org but if i use domain "gmail.com" it fails to deliver.  I am able to use regular google mail and send emails to folks outside my domain.

I tried MailApp and GMailApp and it did not work. I also contacted Google support and they reviewed the admin settings and could not help either.

```
function autoResponder(e){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   Logger.log('on Form Submit');
   Logger.log(e);
   var donorName = e.namedValues['DonorName'][0], donorEmail = e.namedValues['DonorEmail'][0], adminEmail = "secretary@mydomain.org";

   MailApp.sendEmail(donorEmail + ',' + adminEmail, "Donation Receipt", "Sairam "+ donorName + " ,\n\nThank you for your donation.");
}
```

I do get Delivery Status Notification (Failure) email with following details

Message blocked
Your message to admin@mydomain.org has been blocked. See technical details below for more information.
The response was:
Message rejected. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get an email stating the email bounced? Just this info provides very little ground to troubleshoot. Any info you have (errors or whatsoever) would be useful.

Comment: Agree we need more information: does the script generate any errors? Is this just gmail.com or any non mydomain.org emails. Also, your reference to your own domain makes me think this is a G-Suite for business account, not a personal one; correct? So what happens if you try the script from a personal account? Is the user submitting the form the same as the owner of the Sheet the script is bound to? What happens if you cut the form out of the loop, and just run a spreadsheet function to send an email? etc.

Comment: This is a GSuite account.  Here is the error i get in my email box that message is not delivered..                                                                 
Message blocked
Your message to admin@mydomain.org has been blocked. See technical details below for more information.
LEARN MORE
The response was:
Message rejected. See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/69585 for more information.

Comment: What happens if you try to email it to yourself?

Comment: that is successful.  i also tried email without the script and that is successful to anyone outside the domain as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MailApp.sendEmail() in Google Apps Script not sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079323/mailapp-sendemail-in-google-apps-script-not-sending-email)