# How do I use this `GmailApp.sendEmail` function?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a *Send Email* Function(?) that I am using as a part of a Calendar Reservation Approval System. That function(?) looks like this:

```
// Send Email
function sendEmail(request){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: request.email,
    subject: request.subject,
    htmlBody: makeEmail(request)
  })
}
```

Even that function(?) works fine. It runs without bugs etc. However, my account is self-censoring. Basically, my gsuite account is not sending email when coming from this script. I pay for gsuite, so I find this a bit boggling, but oh well, thats for another day.

Apparently [this is the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079323/mailapp-sendemail-in-google-apps-script-not-sending-email)

Basically they say if I alter my existing script(?) to:

```
// Send Email
function sendEmail(request){
  GmailApp.sendEmail({
    to: request.email,
    subject: request.subject,
    htmlBody: makeEmail(request)
  })
}
```

Trouble is, that doesn't fire. So my thinking is that I need to make a minor alteration to the:

```
   to: request.email,
   subject: request.subject,
   htmlBody: makeEmail(request)
```

In order to get it back on track. I didn't write this so I haven't the faintest idea where to start. Anybody wanna help out a lost soul who spent the two hours getting here only to be hamstrung by google thinking I'm a spammer.

Thank you.

I researched the problem of the mail not being sent and figured out that GmailApp.sendEmail is the workaround.

Comment: Would you also be able to share what's being spit out of the `request` in `sendEmail(request)` function? This should look like it would be a lot easier to solve. Would also help to know what being returned via `makeEmail(request)` function.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check if the issue was still affecting you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `sendEmail` method to:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(request.email, request.subject, "", {htmlBody:makeEmail(request)});
```

The `sendEmail()` method uses the method's parameters ([Documentation Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)), only the aditional arguments (like the `htmlBody`) need to get passed as an object.