# Sending emails via google script in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script-editor

trying to send out emails via google script in google sheets (tools->script-editor):

```
    function sendEmails2() { 
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT"; 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Press'); 

var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process 
var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process set to 1, for test purposes

// Fetch the range of cells 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 100) 

// Fetch values for each row in the Range. 
var data = dataRange.getValues(); 

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { 

var row = data[i]; var emailAddress = row[11]; 
var message = row[18]; //
var have_email = row[12]; 
var sendornot = row[16]; 
var emailSent = row[17]; 

if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && have_email == 1 && sendornot == 1) { // Prevents sending duplicates var subject = "Story Pitch"; 

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {'name':'Lisa'}); 
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 18).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted SpreadsheetApp.flush(); } 
} 
}
```

to send out emails. We have this working on two domains, but on one it's not working. Emails bounce back, and the bounce back screen looks the same, regardless of the recipient, a traffic light with a red light on

Message blocked Your message to xyz@gmail.com has been blocked. See technical details below for more information. LEARN MORE

I suspect it's blocked by google. It may have to do with our account status. Manually sent emails go out fine. But emails sent via script do not, they do appear in the sent box, but then bounce back almost instantly.

Does anybody know how to fix this? We have already allowed less secure apps in the g suite security settings but this did not remedy the problem. The g suite access is part of a squarespace deal, so not directly bought from google. The account is around 2 months old now.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello Lisa, could you add to your question post the "technical details" of the issue? You should be able to find this by navigating to the `LEARN MORE` hyperlink in the message you describe in your post. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. The Learn More link leads to this topic, which is not addressing this specific issue: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596?visit_id=637109250661967595-277078801&rd=1

Comment: Hey Lisa, Thanks for your answer. What information does the bounce-back reply that you get have? It should be one of the three that are described in the link you just sent. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hello, thanks. As far as I can tell it's none of the three. 100% sure the message is bounced back by google itself. We managed to send emails via script if we share the spreadhseet with another email account (a gmail.com account say, or a gmail account on another domain), if the account we share it with executes the script, the emails are sent out and arrive at the recipient. But when our new account executes the script, the email shows up in the sent box, and is instantly bounced back, by google itself, internally.

Comment: Hey Lisa, thanks for your answer. The reasons the email may be bouncing are very diverse, and based on the information provided it is rather difficult to find the exact reason. Thus, I'd suggest you consider [contacting G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en). Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MailApp.sendEmail() in Google Apps Script not sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079323/mailapp-sendemail-in-google-apps-script-not-sending-email)